# How does Google Music "Scan and Match" feature match music?

Tags: google-play-music

Almost none of my music is being matched, whether the albums in question are popular or obscure.

The service didn't find a match to any of my Bob Dylan, LCD Soundsystem, Stars of the Lid, or Dinosaur Jr. albums. It was only able to match Melvins' Houdini. This was even after I made sure that the metadata matched the Play Store's.

Comment: My guess is that Google uses both metadata and actual file content. Their Instant Mix feature also compares the actual sound data to other songs to find similar songs, so I think Google could use file contents as well.
Keep in mind that Google does not have contracts with all music labels yet, so it's possible that popular artists are not yet in their offering.

Comment: I think you might be right about the record labels. Since Atlantic Records owns Melvins' Houdini, I tried another one of their artists, Janelle Monae, and it was able to match 16 of the 18 tracks.